# C++ execute function without if check each time

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a bool variable(global or local) & a function which is present. The function should execute only when the bool variable is true. Since this function is repeated many times & I need a way to execute this function without performing if the bool variable is true everytime.

```
function();
bool executeFun = true;

if(executeFun){
function();
}
..
if(executeFun){
function();
}
```

.. Need to execute `function()` without checking bool each time.
Thanks :)

Comment: Put all the function calls in one if statement.

Comment: What is your concern here - extra typing or performance?

Comment: @SergeyA extra typing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap it in another function.

```
auto perhaps = executeFun ? function : +[](){};
perhaps();
perhaps();
perhaps();
```

Comment: +[](){} - is this a lambda or any sort of expression for void?

Comment: @Niyas It's an empty lambda, the + is a trick to get it to implicitly convert to a function pointer.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a function pointer that you set after having checked the condition:

```
#include <iostream>

using func_t = void(*)();

int main() {
    func_t p = []{};
    
    p(); // does nothing
    
    if(true) p = []{ std::cout << "doing something\n"; };

    p(); // does something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you move the `bool` check inside the function?

```cpp
void function();
bool executeFun = true;

void function() {
    if (!executeFun) return;
    ...
}

...

function();
...
function();
```